# How can I get Solve to combine Sin/Cos into Tan?

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation

I want to solve an equation in `x`, containing `Sin[x]`, `Cos[x]` and a positive real constant `b`:

```
Solve[Cos[x] - b Sin[x] == 0 && x > 0 && x < π && b > 0,x]
```

*Mathematica* returns

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[-2 ArcTan[b - Sqrt[1 + b^2]], b > 0]}}
> ```

If I manually bring `Cos[x]` to the other side of the equation:

```
Solve[1 == b Sin[x]/Cos[x] && x > 0 && x < π && b > 0,x]
```

*Mathematica* returns

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[1/b], b > 0]}}
> ```

which is the solution that I prefer to see (I am aware of the fact that the solutions are equivalent for `b > 0`).

My question: can I impose conditions on `Solve` such that it internally rephrases my equation from

```
Cos[x] - b Sin[x] == 0
```

to

```
1 == b Sin[x]/Cos[x]
```

or can this be performed with other *Mathematica* commands in advance of using `Solve`?

Comment: `Solve[b == First[b /. FullSimplify@Solve[Cos[x] - b Sin[x] == 0 && Pi/2 > x > 0, b]], x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to include a double-angle identity in the transformations tried by `Simplify`:

```
doubleangle = # /. t_ArcTan :> 1/2 Simplify@ArcTan[TrigExpand@Tan[2 t]] &;

Simplify[
 Solve[Cos[x] - b Sin[x] == 0 && x > 0 && x < π && b > 0, x],
 TransformationFunctions -> {doubleangle, Automatic}]
(*  {{x -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[1/b], b > 0]}} *))
```

One advantage or drawback, according to one's own point of view, is that the form ultimately returned will be the one that *Mathematica* counts as "simpler."  See [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html), [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) and [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Belisarus in his comment gave one solution which can be referred to as a post-processing. Here is the pre-processing as you mentioned:

```
 eq = Cos[x] - b Sin[x] == 0;
Map[Divide[#, Cos[x]] &, eq] // Expand
(*        1 - b Tan[x] == 0           *)
```

In my version 10, however, your equation is perfectly solved by itself yielding

```
Solve[eq,x]
  (*   {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-(b/Sqrt[1 + b^2]), -(1/Sqrt[1 + b^2])] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[b/Sqrt[1 + b^2], 1/Sqrt[1 + b^2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}   *)
```

The solution refers to any `b`, while the conditional expression is only related to the fact that `C[1]`are integers. If you prefer to only work with positive `b`s you just simplify it

```
Simplify[Solve[eq, x], b > 0]

(*  {{x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[1/b] + \[Pi] (-1 + 2 C[1]), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[1/b] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
*)
```

Have fun!